# Random word From Core-data (NSString)

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a core-data model with a Entity called Goodie with Attribute called thingsYouWant of type String.

i want  to pick a random word from "thingsYouWant" when u push a button, and put that in a string with format.

but i keep getting a NSString may not respond to  objectAtIndex error ;-(

Update:

here is my working code:

```
-( void ) viewDidLoad {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Goodie" inManagedObjectContext:
             self.managedObjectContext ]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext 
                    executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (array == nil)
    {
        // Deal with error...
    }

    if(array.count > 0){
              int r = random()% [array count];
       goodie = [array objectAtIndex:r];

    } else { // no one to fetch - generate one
        goodie = [NSEntityDescription
            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Goodie"
            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext ];
    }



- (void) winText {          

NSArray *components = [[goodie thingsYouWant] 
                          componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSInteger randomIndex = (random() % [components count]);
NSString *newWord = [components objectAtIndex:randomIndex];


winLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Congratulations, 
               the carrot you have earned is -->>> %@", newWord];
```

}

Thank you :-D

Skov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `array.count` is an improper use of dot syntax.  `count` is not a property of `NSArray` but a method call.

Second, which line is giving you the error?  Are you getting it at the `[array objectAtIndex:0]` or at `[goodie.thingsYouWant objectAtIndex:R]`?  If it is the latter then you need to see what the property `thingsYouWant` is defined as.  I suspect it is a string property.

### Update

If you want to grab a word out of a string then you need to split the string up into an array.  Using the method `-componentsSeparatedByString:`.  From there you can then grab one of them at random.

An example of this would be:

```
NSArray *components = [[goodie thingsYouWant] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSInteger randomIndex = (random() % [components count]);
NSString *newWord = [components objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```

Comment: the error is in [goodie.thingsYouWant objectAtIndex:R]  and yes its a @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * thingsYouWant; in my NSManagedObject.

Comment: Then that is your bug. You are calling `-objectAtIndex:` on a `NSString`.

Comment: i cinder figured that from the error msg,  but every where iv seen ppl asking similar question  they use objectAtIndex, so for me to find a random word, i my core data NSString  i have to pub a array with the data from that string and the find a random word???

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this statement of yours

> Goodie with Attribute called
>   thingsYouWant of type String

I am with Marcus S. Zarra

Please have a look at [Non-Standard Persistent Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919) to store your array in core data.

Comment: the problem is not how to store the data, that works fine, i want to retrive a random "word" stored in my core data, and add that word to in the end of the text in the "Label" (UITextView).